# Force Page Break before Row based off formula?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am new to crystal reports. I have built a simple report that is populated by values from a stored procedure. I'm trying to place a page break before the row if the value of one of the returned items from the stored procedure is equal to a specific string. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Crystal Reports, in the Section Expert under the Paging tab you should have the option to specify page breaks using a formula.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Right click on the section like Report Detail, Report footer etc and there will be an option to insert page break.
Against that option there will be a symbol of formula.
In the formula, specify the formula:

```
if(Report field...)="comparable string"
then true
else false
```

And you are done. You can ask again if this is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can break a page using section expert.

Steps for produce:-

Right Click on Detail Section->Click on Section Expert->Click On Paging Tab->select CheckBox(New page Before) ->Click on Formula Button.

here will open a popup window and put below code in formula window.

if{YOUR_REPORT_FIELD_NAME}="xyz" then
True 
else
False

when your field value find "xyz" then page will be break.

if want any clarification , please comment.